# (php get content ) how can i use foreach loop to rid retrieving one string

Tags: php, url, foreach, file-get-contents

I'm trying to get content of some table from url but it always gets one string.

I was wondering if I could use foreach loop to get all strings which is in the table like:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.w3.org/WAI/UA/2002/06/thead-test';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$first_step = explode( '<td>' , $content );
$second_step = explode('</td>' , $first_step[1] );
$output = $second_step[0];
echo $output;
?>
```

I found some link after some research, but it couldn't help me that much.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not completely clear what you what here... you want to get the content of all the strings between table cells (`<td>xxx</td>`)?

```
$url = 'https://www.w3.org/WAI/UA/2002/06/thead-test';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
preg_match_all('#<td>(.*?)</td>#m', $content, $matches);
$output = $matches[1];
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: Yes. but i can't make it. even your code is not successful :/

Comment: Let's say getting content of this url.
https://zabihullah.com/watch/yt/txt.php

I want to get all the string between <p>x</p> from one too five

Comment: Whoops; sorry.  preg_match_all always surprises me how it builds its matches array.  Edited above and fixed.

Comment: Thankyou. can you output in plain txt?

Comment: `echo implode(' ', $matches[1]);`

Comment: YES I FOUND IT. THANX SO MUCH :D